# Is there a biometrics fingerprint scanner that directly sends raw biometrics data?

Tags: biometrics

I have this payroll project where my client wants to use biometrics to easily keep track the time attendances of his 400 employees. However, the problem is his company has a high employee turnover rate. 
It implies that the biometrics fingerprint scanner which usually has only a limited number of available fingerprint templates from 1000 to 2000, the biometrics may eventually run out of memory.

The better solution I can think of is to use the payroll system directly as the data store for the biometrics fingerprint scanner. However, I can't seem to find any biometrics fingerprint scanner that allows to send raw biometrics data to the computer for storage.

Is there a biometrics scanner available in the market where it offers an SDK which allows developers to interface the scanner directly to the software so that it can be used as a large data store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least Cytron has a model, that says (embhasis my own):

> - Direct access to any MCU through Serial UART operation and integrated with low current warning.
> - Able to retrieve fingerprint **raw data** and fingerprint identity files.

https://www.cytron.com.my/p-sn-fpr-uart

It is little bit expensive, but you are supposed to find a cheaper too because there exists so many general purpose fingerprint sdks in Github and they won't be made for one manufacturer only.

Write to Google Search: *github fingerprint detection* for sdks.